# 2017 moderator election requested

Tags: discussion, election

To keep you informed - we (the moderators) recently requested an election for two new moderator positions for CrossValidated. It should begin soon.

Our election pages are here (which currently link to our three previous elections):

https://stats.stackexchange.com/election/

The new election won't appear there until the election has been officially announced here on meta but you can look at past elections to get a sense for how they work.

Meta posts announcing the start of the election and for the process of gathering [questions](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2432/2015-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) for [candidates to answer](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2460/2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire) should appear in the near future.  (My links are to the corresponding pages for the 2015 elections, not to the upcoming one)

Please consider whether you'd like to nominate for moderator in that upcoming election.

---

**What does a moderator do?**

[Who are the moderators and what is their role?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators)

[More on moderators and their role from the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role)

[A theory of moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) (Jeff Atwood's original 2009 post about moderation)

**Who can nominate?** See the coloured box in the sidebar for our previous election [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/election/3) -- a similar sidebar should appear for our upcoming election.

**Who can vote?** See the coloured box in the sidebar on the "tab=election" page for our previous election [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/election/3?tab=election) -- a similar sidebar should appear for our upcoming election.

[Questions about what moderators do (hopefully not already covered by available resources) may be posted to meta any time. It may be best to wait until the official announcement to do so, but if you have general questions on the election process, feel free to ask them here on meta using the tag [election](/questions/tagged/election).]

Comment: I considered it but decided against doing so; the election announcement itself will be featured soon. I mostly wanted to make sure the people that are actively interested in the site (and so check here regularly) were aware it was coming.  However, if there's clear desire that it be featured I can do so.

Comment: Is there any particular reason that motivated this all of a sudden?

Comment: I wouldn't say it was sudden.

Comment: @gung To at least partly answer the question; it was for several months clear that the moderators were at the point of needing more help -- which is only to be expected as the site has grown - we had elections in 2011, 2013 and 2015 so it's not especially surprising that we would need another sometime soon. That wasn't the only factor in the timing -- for one example, if I want to continue being able to answer questions at all, I will need to reduce my allocation of time to moderation for an extended period, as my total time on site will have to reduce (/already has, but will reduce further).

Comment: Make CrossValidated great again!

Comment: @amoeba: Will that be your campaign slogan?

Comment: @Scortchi I am not planning to participate to be honest.

Comment: @amoeba I'm very sad to hear that; I think you'd be excellent. ... And just think of the times you wouldn't need to wait on a moderator to fix some tag-synonym issue

Comment: @amoeba: That's a shame! I'd go so far as to say that your work on tags alone qualifies you for the position (& it'd become easier if you had mod. privileges).

Comment: Glen_b and @Scortchi: Thank you. It's true that being a mod would allow me to handle the tag issues more effectively... At the same time, I am not sure I would really be such a good candidate: e.g. my participation in review queues has always been zero (ZERO!), meaning I have no experience in doing it and little interest to start, whereas I believe this is an important part of any mod's job. I even considered running for a mod on a platform of becoming a "tag mod", but honestly I am not sure if "specialization mods" would be such a good idea.

Comment: @amoeba The whole process depends on division of labour. Conversely, I've never got excited about tags, yet done some other things. But your work on tags is spectacular and with your reputation of 39K  and overall good citizenship makes you a very strong candidate should you be persuaded to stand.