# Small interest in 2017 moderator election..?

Tags: discussion, moderation, election

How is that a [thread announcing moderator election](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4885/2017-moderator-election-requested) got +21 and multiple comments, [thread on questions to moderators](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4887/2017-moderator-election-qa-question-collection?noredirect=1&lq=1) got +17 and multiple answers, yet, until now, I'm the only person who nominated himself..?

If we need "at least two more" moderators, then I'm afraid, that it won't make much difference if we get only one moderator more.

Comment: I would be interesting in becoming a mod in the long-term. Nonetheless I am not sure if I am already mature enough. I am lacking rep, experience in SE and knowledge about certain statistical fields. Should I nominate myself and let the community decide or should I wait and apply maybe in 3 or 4 years? I sticked to waiting until now. Maybe someone is feeling the same way as I do and therefore we do not have enough candidates. Disclosure: Please do not consider my comment as impolite I know I am just an "intermediate beginner or so" and I appreciate learning from people who know more than me.

Comment: @Ferdi: What you describe is very reasonable. Nevertheless the issue is not if one is "knowledgable" in terms of Statistics. Given one can appreciate Statistics to a reasonable extent, moderation tasks (tags, review queue, spam/offensive posts, etc.) entail mainly interpersonal and organisational skills. That being said, if I do not know of a candidate and I have not read their responses and interactions with other users I cannot judge their interpersonal and organisational skills either.

Comment: There's lots of areas of statistics that I know little about. Time series, for example. Or neural nets.  Yet I'm a mod.  Experience in SE would be a bigger problem.

Answer (score 11):

If I recall correctly, in the last two elections some nominations came in the last couple of days of the nomination period; that may be the case again.

<strike>At most</strike> two moderators will be elected this election -- we only requested two slots even though I said on chat the other day that I felt we could use three (for reasons that may be becoming clear now).

Comment: Clarification on the election rules: you mentioned in chat that if there are <=2 nominees then they become mods automatically. Does it mean that if nobody apart from Tim nominates themselves until 1 min before the end of nomination time, then anybody can hijack the election by nominating themselves in the last moment and automatically getting the mod position, however bad this candidate might be?

Comment: DataScience SE's election's nomination phase got extended by a week cause there were only 2 candidates who were up for nomination for 3 slots.  afaik there should be `n+1` nominees for an election to happen

Comment: @Dawny33 Interesting.

Comment: @amoeba: I didn't know that, but it seems to be a rule -  https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2298/3361, https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2108 - at least for sites graduating from beta.

Comment: @Dawny33: By the way - well done! https://datascience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2277/3361

Comment: @amoeba: Not just for beta sites - https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/627.

Comment: @Dawny thanks for that information; that's news to me.

Comment: @Dawny33 As you probably know, we have had several Meta discussions about datascience.SE (see [meta-tag:datascience-stackexchange]) with I would describe as a very strong consensus that having datascience.SE separate from CV is a bad idea (e.g. 42 upvotes and not a single downvote here https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2281/28666, but see also other Qs and As). Now I can see that datascience.SE is going to graduate from beta, despite the mentioned consensus... Well well. Would you perhaps want to post an announcement on our Meta?

Comment: @Scortchi Interesting about datascience.SE. See my comment above.

Comment: @amoeba To be explicit, just in case anyone reading along is unclear -- my understanding was incorrect; apparently what I thought is not how election works (to my surprise)

Comment: @amoeba: I hadn't noticed till now. It might be useful to have a Meta post explaining what's on topic at DS, as it could be a migration path for questions that would currently be closed here.

Comment: @amoeba Sure. Will ask one of the mods to :)